# General Derivative for Negative Binomial Probability Generating Function

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives

> Find $\cfrac{dh_M^k}{ds}$ for $h_M(s)=p^r (1-qs)^{-r}$

I know from calculus $y=x^n$, then $dy/dx=nx^{n-1}$.  So I thought I'd take a few derivatives and see a pattern then generalize:

$\cfrac{dh_M}{ds}=(-r)p^r(1-qs)^{-r-1}(-q)$ for $k=1$

$\cfrac{dh_M^2}{ds}=(-r-1)(-r)p^r(1-qs)^{-r-1}(-q)^2$ for $k=2$

$\vdots $

$\cfrac{dh_M^k}{ds}=(-r-k+1)(-r-k+2)\cdots(-r-1)(-r)p^r(1-qs)^{-r-1}(-q)^k \text{ for } k=k \tag{1}$

My question is how do you simply the signs on (1).  Obviously for the coefficients you can factor the negative sign:  $(-r-k+1)=-(r+k-1) \cdots $, and q will be negative depending on whether k is odd or even.  I don't see how to simplify to get this result:

$\cfrac{dh_M^k}{ds}=(r+k-1)(r+k-2)\cdots r q^k p^r(1-qs)^{-r-1} \text{ for } k=k$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us forget about the $p^r$ part. You can insert it later. We find the $k$-th derivative of $1-qs)^{-r}$. Like you, we will take it one step at a time. The first derivative is $(-q)(-r)(1-qs)^{-(r+1)}$, or more simply
$$qr(1-qs)^{-(r+1)}.$$
The second derivative is $(qr)(-q)(-(r+1))(1-qs)^{-(r+2)}$. This simplifies to
$$q^2r(r+1)(1-qs)^{-(r+2)}.$$
The pattern is I think already clear. The $k$-th derivative is 
$$q^rr(r+1)\cdots (r+k-1) (1-qs)^{-(r+k)}.$$
Note that most of the minus signs have thoughfully disappeared. One could do a formal induction to prove the correctness of the formula, but there really seems to be not much reason for that.

Not that this is an improvement, but the $r(r+1)\cdots (r+k-1)$ part could be written as $\binom{r+k-1}{r-1}$.